# How do I create a filter based on the current user's role in a search_api based view?

Tags: 8, views, search

I would like to filter a search_api based view using the current user's roles as input.
I don't see a contextual filter for the current user in my search_api based content view at all.
How can I accomplish something like the ["Published or has role" feature of this contrib module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_published_or_roles)? This one seems to only work on non-search_api views.

Comment: Try adding a Relationship for User ID, then the Contextual may appear. Sorry I haven't checked this, flying blind for now.

Comment: @prkos There is an option to add a relationship to the Author but I am not interested in the Author. I just want the current site user.

Comment: What is the connection between user roles and your content?

Comment: If they are staff they can see it even if it is unpublished. If not the view should be filtered by published. I can't use the trick of putting two views on one path since this view is embedded in a block field.

Comment: This sounds like a node access issue. If you have node access properly sorted out so that only appropriate roles see restricted content Views will honor that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @prkos reminding me that this is a regular node access setup issue. This was solved when I found [this issue in the search_api queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/3075684) about incompatibility with "View All Unpublshed content"